# I need to pass an integer to the 'td:nth'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to java script and HTML developing. I need to pass a variable to the `$('td:nth(int))`. I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
var index=2;
alert($('td:nth(index)').html);
```

Comment: `var index=2; alert($('td:nth-child(' + index + ')').html());`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple string concatenation. But there is some bugs in your code:

1. There is no pseudo-class selector like `:nth()` , you can use **[`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** or **[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** pseudo-class selector or .
2. There is no `html` property for jQuery object it will be `undefined`, instead use **[`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)** method.

---

```
 var index=2; 
 alert($('td:nth-child(' + index + ')').html());
```

Comment: @SubodhaTillakaratna : glad to help you :)